# TruffleConsole: Not able to send Ether to an account using Smart Contract’s method

Tags: solidity, truffle-console

I have got a smart contract (SC) which is using transfer to send Ether. The transaction is happening but the balance of the account is not increasing.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
   contract TransferTest{
      uint8  public testVal =97;
      function testFunc(address payable addr) public returns (uint8){
         addr.transfer(testVal);
         return testVal;
      }     
}
```

I am using `accounts[2]`. Truffle console is showing the transaction of calling the `testFunc()` but the balance of SC and the `accounts[2]` i.e. acc2 is not changing:

```
truffle(development)>TC = await TransferTest.at(addr)
truffle(development)> balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(TC.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether")
'193.999999999999999903'
truffle(development)> acc2 = accounts[2]
'0x20642D4d868da20f5268b0Be7d52fD26FcD9940d'
truffle(development)> b2 = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(b2, "ether")
'100.000000000000000097'
truffle(development)> await TC.testFunc(acc2)
{ tx:
   '0xb751de0c31147d2baf2330c50c62c70facacf3e35e201061c12260bda601e4df',
  receipt:
truffle(development)> b2 = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(b2, "ether")
'100.000000000000000194'
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not transferring any ether when calling the function; thus, no ether is sent to the target address. In order to send ether you should:

1. Make the function payable
2. Send ether to the target address through `msg.value`

Therefore, you can update your smart contract with something like this:

```
pragma solidity =0.5.0;
 
   contract TransferTest{
       
      function testFunc(address payable addr) public payable {
         addr.transfer(msg.value);
      }
}
```

And then, send some ether when calling the `testFunc()`:

```
 await TC.testFunc(acc2, {value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')})
```

** **UPDATE** **

Alternatively, if you want to keep the function as is, you need to send ether first in order to effectively transfer it afterwards. You can create either a payable function to deposit ether or a payable constructor, for instance:

```
pragma solidity =0.5.0;

   contract TransferTest{
      uint8  public testVal = 97;
      
      constructor () public payable {}
      
      function testFunc(address payable addr) public {
         addr.transfer(testVal);
      }  
}
```

And yet a final remark: you are actually sending 97 weis. That's why in your tests, there was apparently some ether beforehand in the contract and when you do the transfer, what you did is `100.000000000000000097`(initial balance) + `0.000000000000000097` (testVal: 97) = `100.000000000000000194`

Comment: Thanks, God blesses you, why balance of acc2 is increasing from '100.000000000000000097' to  '100.000000000000000194' when testFunc(...) is not payable???

Comment: Why balance is not increasing to '197.000000000000000097'??

Comment: 'payable' means that a function is capable of receiving Ether, I don't think it is related to transferring Ether? please guide.

Comment: Please see my update in the answer. The key point is sending ether to the contract beforehand.

Comment: I am getting the error: truffle(development)> acc3 = accounts[3]
'0x96fDD9a15Ed103bD585B6CD690dB1aB1125EA024'
truffle(development)> await TC.testFunc(acc3, {value: web3.utils.toWei('100', 'ether')})
Thrown:
{ Error: Returned error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 100134439500000000000 and the sender's account only has: 99988745980000000000
If we declare testFunc(...) as payable then (smart contract i.e. TransferTest) SC would receive ether from acc3, this is not I want. I want to send Ether from SC to acc3. @Sergi, your solution is wrong. Guide me, Zulfi.

Comment: The error is because the address calling the function has 99.9 ETH and you are trying to transfer 100 ETH => Just decrease the transfer value (e.g.: 95 ETH). The solution is fine => again, either you declare the testFunc function payable, or declare a fallback / deposit function payable or declare the constructor payable to be able to send ETH and then do the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
   contract TransferTest{
      uint  public testVal =97 ether;//Note we can't use uint8 with 97 ether
      function testFunc(address payable addr) public returns (uint) {//when we use payable SC would receive Ether
         //addr.transfer(msg.value); We can't use msg.value, it would give an error, msg.value can be used only if function is payable
         addr.transfer(testVal);
         return testVal;
      }     
      function  deposit() payable public{}
}
```